# Why does Entity Framework require the DTC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, msdtc

Whenever I either call a stored procedure or a linq query I get an error saying the DTC is not enabled for network access.
But I don't need this to be running - there are no distributed transactions here.

Why would this be happening?

Is there some EF setting I need to update to say there are no distributed transactions?

I appreciate I should post some example code, even though this happens everywhere, so here it is:

```
            // breaks at the 'connections = ...' line
            using (var context = new DbEntities())
            {
                connections = (from c in context.Connections
                               where c.Email == email
                               select c.SignalRConnectionId).ToList();
            }
```

Error message:

> "MSDTC on server 'local' is unavailable."

(I did ask this elsewhere but I think the question had too much detail, so nobody answered)

**Please note: I know how to enable the DTC, however I shouldn't need to do this as there are no distributed transactions going on.**

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server you use? Is there TransactionScope used anywhere?

Comment: SQL 2012. TransactionScope is used elsewhere but this works fine without the DTC enabled; do I need to use the same method throughout the application? (Will try this anyway!)

Comment: But I mean if TransactionScope is used in cases when you encounter this problem? Maybe there are nested contexts there (so, multiple contexts anywhere higher in the call stack?). Just using single DbContext without transaction scopes or nesting should not escalate to distributed transaction.

Comment: Possibly, but if so these all work fine without the DTC. So would this mean I need to do this in all cases within this nested context?

Comment: Well you better provide more code examples which include all you do, including those TransactionScopes so we can give better advice.

Comment: I mean code example which includes all code which does anything with transactions and database connections up the call stack, not just code where it actually fails with exception.

Comment: Yup gotcha. Actually i wrapped my database call in a transaction scope and that fixed the problem! So thanks :) If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't think that really solves the problem, only hides it under the carpet, and you might encounter it again and again if you won't understand why exactly it happens. I mean you should not wrap everything in TransactionScope, it should work perfectly fine without that.

Comment: You are probably right. There may well be deep seated issues that are causing this to happen. Unfortunately, this is legacy code that I have been asked to modify; unfortunately I don't have the luxury of being able to investigate further, although I will make recommendations to that effect.